# React router doesn't work correct with component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to render container component if path matches.

```
class MyTopComponent extends Component {
componentDidUpdate() {
    const params = getUrlParams(this.props.location);
    if (params.id && params.id !== this.props.id) {
        this.props.updateId(params.id);
    }
}
render() {
    const { a, b, c } = getUrlParams(this.props.location);
    return this.props.id && this.props.isDataReady ? (
    <div>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={MY_FIRST_PATH} component={MyContainer}/>
    </Switch>
    </div>
    ) : null;
}
}
```

The problem is that after going to path, then back, then to path again, page crashes.
It works fine when I use inline function in component:

```
<Route path={MY_FIRST_PATH} component={() => <MyContainer/>}/>
```

Is the second way good in performance?

Comment: Where is `MY_FIRST_PATH` defined?

Comment: it's a constant

Answer (score 0):

If `MY_FIRST_PATH` is a constanct I assume it will resolve to a string i.e. `'MY_FIRST_PATH'`, but in your path prop you need to have `path='/MY_FIRST_PATH'`. Very likely you forgot your `/`

Comment: component={() => <MyContainer/>} works fine
component={MyContainer} doesn't work (crash after go to path, back, go to path again)

Comment: You can't use `component={() => <MyContainer/>}`. The prop component should only be used to render a component directly i.e. `component={MyContainer}`. So, for an inline function you should be using render={()=> <MyContainer/>}. Try to do a ternary check inside your Route based on your props, something like that:
`<Route path='/MY_FIRST_PATH' render={()=> propIsTrue ? <MyContainer/> : <Redirect to='/' /> } />`